# How to get iframe source from page_source when the id isn't on the iframe

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Hello today i wanna ask how to get the link inside the page source but without id, i asked before how to get the link with id ok now i understand, but i've tried the same method with another link and i was not successful about that so here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver_path = r"C:\Users\666\Desktop\New folder (8)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
# go to the google home page
driver.get("https://www.gledalica.com/sa-prevodom/iron-fist-s02e01-video_02cb355f8.html")



# find the element that's name attribute is q (the google search box)
element = driver.find_element_by_id("Playerholder")
frame = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame("iframe")
link = frame.get_attribute("src")

driver.quit()
```

Like this here: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJSt6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [multiple way to get it](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html). In this case one of easiest is by using a CSS selector:

```
frame = find_element_by_css_selector('#Playerholder iframe')
```

This looks for the element with `id = "Playerholder"` in the html and then look for a child of it that is an iframe.